# IDEA - Custom Errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, compiler-warnings, facet

While working on my code I was reminded of just how much IDEA does for me. This gave me the idea, what if I could add some custom compile time processing. In which, if my code is invalid it will prompt me with an error. Say for example I left a return type as a null when it should never be null. Basically framework and API checks to reduce production errors.

The problem is I have no clue where to start on doing this. I assume I need to develop a plugin but am having issues finding documentation. If someone would be so kind as to help me get started. As well maybe even provide links to example projects or existing projects (github if possible).

As well I plan to release this plugin as part of a few APIs I develop. So helping me will help others in the long run :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an intellij plugin that implements custom `inspections`.

Example here:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inspection+of+Code+Source

The inspections that you create can highlight code red, allow the user to disable them, and also prompt for fixes. Please see intellij plugin development API's for more details.

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

You can use standard java assertions for this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html